# Manga about a poor noble girl who wakes up in the body of a duke's daughter

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I'm looking for the title of a Japanese manga that I read few months ago.

A poor noble girl suddenly wakes up in the body of a duke's daughter. The duke's daughter was about to be imprisoned and that's when she woke up and found herself imprisoned in a room. Later, she becomes close with the guard. The girl is a self taught herbalist. She was abused by her stepmom and sister.

The duke's daughter is the greatest magician in the kingdom. She swapped her body with someone else to escape punishment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[I Awoke as an Imprisoned Villainess](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/4mjw4d8/megasametara-tougokusareta-akujo-datta)***...?

> Sophia Alcott, the daughter of Earl Alcott, lives a lonely life as a maligned and infamous shut in, with nothing to do but to work on her skills as a budding apothecary in the dusty storeroom she's forced to call home. That is until she suddenly wakes up one day and finds herself in the body of an even more infamous villainess (one who actually earned her reputation) locked up in a tower. But although the only clue she has about how this happened is a cryptic note, instead of despairing about her new situation, she's in awe at just how luxurious the treatment she's receiving in this 'prison' is compared to how she had to live before.

At the start of the manga, the villainess daughter of a duke, Lady Violet Elford, is being taken to a tower to be imprisoned for humiliating the Crown Prince's fiancée. Just before entering the tower, she secretly casts a spell to switch bodies with another girl, Sophia Alcott, and then immediately collapses unconscious.

> [image: "I Awoke as an Imprisoned Villainess," chapter 1, page 1.]

Sophia is the daughter of an earl, but her mother passed away when she was three, and since then she's lived with her stepmother and younger half-sister who've made her live in squalor in her own home. Despite this, she managed to teach herself to become an apothecary by reading books left to her by her mother.

When Sophia wakes up in Violet's body, she's in a bed with a uniformed man standing close by. He's Claude Bradley, a knight who's under orders to keep an eye on her. He's initially sceptical when Sophia claims not to be Violet, but since he knows Violet is gifted at magic, it slowly occurs to him that Sophia may not be lying.

> [image: "I Awoke as an Imprisoned Villainess," chapter 2, page 33.]

Comment: Yes this is the one. Thank you so much 